# iOS 13.4 Date Picker compact not highlighting current day or change blurred background when picker is shown?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, datepicker, ios14

Is it possible to not highlight current day in iOS 13.4 DatePicker  - compact preferredDatePickerStyle, to achieve that all days have non highlighted color ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these:

```
self.startDatePicker.setValue(UIColor.clear, forKey: "textColor")
self.startDatePicker.setValue(false, forKey: "highlightsToday")
```

Comment: Currently not working on iOS 13.4, app crashes